# Delete all lines that match a given beginning and 2 possible ends

Tags: regex, sed

I want to suppress into a file all the lines that match the following requirements :

- The line begin with ' *' (a space followed by a star)
- The line ends with either '.cpp' or '.hpp'

I dont care about the content between that 
So for instance, this should show up

- `*  ns1/file.cpp`
- `*        file2.hpp`

I tried the following command 
`sed -e '/^ \**(\.[hc]pp)$/d' file`

But it does not match the lines.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `.*` in between to match arbitrary text:

```
sed '/^ \*.*\.[hc]pp$/d' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
egrep -v '^ [*].*[.][ch]pp$' YourFilePattern
```

for an alternative to sed